# zsh: is there a problem with always enabling extended glob?

Tags: zsh, wildcards, rc

I recetnly came across

```
setopt extended_glob
```

...in order to enable extended globbing which allows for a number of cool wildcard additions, like excluding specific patterns, for example:

```
ls ^foo*
```

...will use `ls` on every path in your current directory except for patterns that match `foo*`.

I found one tutorial suggesting to put `setopt extended_glob` inside your `.zshrc`, but I guess since many zsh config templates miss that option and the option being *disabled by default* it has some downsides or even side-effects?

Or is it absolutely harmless always enabling `extended_glob` via putting it inside one's `.zshrc`?

Comment: [When you run `zsh` interactively, it reads your `~/.zshrc` (and also the system `/etc/zshrc` ). You're likely to set a few options there that modify how `zsh` expands commands, in particular `extended_glob` (_which should be the default, if `zsh` didn't choose to be backward compatible with the early 1990s when this option doesn't exist_).](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199254/22142)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would assume the potential issue is that `^` is quite a valid character in file names, so the meaning of a pattern containing it changes based on if the option is set or not:

```
$ touch 'foo' 'bar' '^foo' '^bar'
$ ls ^foo*
^foo
$ setopt extendedglob
$ ls ^foo*           
bar  ^bar  ^foo
```

A standard shell would take the `^` as an ordinary character, so the feature is probably disabled by default for compatibility.

As long as you remember what options are enabled, i.e. know how the shell interprets the globs, leaving `extended_glob` enabled shouldn't be a problem in interactive use.

For scripts that don't expect it but use weird filenames, it would be an issue, but non-interactive shells shouldn't read `.zshrc`, so setting it there should be ok. Just don't set it in `.zshenv`.

---

The ksh-style extended globs (`@(...|...)` etc., `setopt kshglob`) have a similar issue in that they conflict with how zsh handles parenthesis in globs. `@(f|b)` means different things depending on if `kshglob` is set or not.

Comment: Note that `^` is special in several other shells (Bourne, rc, akanga, es, fish). Also in csh, tcsh, bash when the first character of a command line. `a~b` (also special with extendedglob) is not special in any though.

Comment: ksh globs also conflict with Bourne/POSIX when used in expansions. For instance `a='@(*)'; echo $a` is meant to output the file names that start with `@(` and end with `)` but outputs all non-hidden files instead `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob -o globsubst -o nobareglobquals`. ksh does not recognise them when used in the result of expansions.

Comment: `^` is also often used in git commands,  such as `git diff HEAD^` which makes the use of it in zsh quite problematic if you use git often.

Comment: @Zaroth so are *'s and those are all likely to be expanded inside quotes anyway.